If $f \circ f$ is the identity, then $f(x) = x^{-1}$ for every $x \in G$
Let $G$ be a finite group and $f \in \text{Aut}(G)$ (an automorphism of $G$) that fixes only the identity element of $G$.

Prove that the function $h: G \to G$ defined by $h(x) = x^{-1}f(x)$ is bijective.

Prove that if $f \circ f$ is the identity, then $f(x) = x^{-1}$ for every $x \in G$.


I got stucked in the 2nd part, perhaps one could use the fact in 1. but I'm not sure. Thanks a lot for the help!
Here's my solution to 1:
Injective
$a^{-1}f(a) = b^{-1}f(b) \quad ; \quad f(ab^{-1}) = ab^{-1} \implies ab^{-1} = e \quad , \quad a = b$
Surjective
$a \in G$ solving for $x$ gives: $ a = x^{-1}f(x) = f(g^{-1})f(x) \quad ; \quad a = f(g^{-1}x) \quad ; \quad g f^{-1}(a) = x$
The second equality comes from the fact that $f$ is an automorphism, so $\exists g\in G / f(g)=x$
For the second part I got stucked at the beginning, my idea is to try and see how it can be that $f(x)x=e$ or something similar...

Inversion is only a group automorphism if the group is abelian.

Well, the third part of the exercise is to then show that G is abelian... so I guess I'll try to see the iff, thanks

The return part is not hard, just check $f(x^{-1}y^{-1})$

You should edit the question and include your solution to (1) and explain where you got stuck in (2). Otherwise this will attract close votes for missing context.

I am sure that this problem has been treated elsewhere on Math StackExchange. Look further!

You do not need to show surjectivity of $h$. Any injective function from a finite set to itself must also be surjective (and vice versa, any surjective function from a finite set to itself must also be injective).

Also, if your argument for surjectivity were correct, then it would still hold for infinite groups, as nowhere in your argument does it require $G$ to be finite. But in fact, counterexamples exist in the infinite case. Consider for example $G=\mathbb{Z}[1/3]$  (the subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ consisting of fractions whose denominator is a power of $3$) with the automorphism $f(x)=3x$. Then, $h(x)=2x$ is injective but not surjective.

True, now I see the problem, introducing $g$, a value that depends on $x$, didn't solve the problem at all...

$$\text{Please do not type like this.}$$

If $f\circ f = \operatorname{id}_G$ then you have
$$f(h(x)) = f(x^{-1}f(x)) = f(x)^{-1} x = (x^{-1}f(x))^{-1} = h(x)^{-1}$$
But since $h$ is bijective, you have
$$f(x) = f(h(h^{-1}(x))) = h(h^{-1}(x))^{-1} = x^{-1}$$
The question $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is a group morphism $\iff G$ is abelian is a different matter: it will be used in the last question to prove the following fact:
There exists an involution in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ having only one fixed point $\implies G$ is abelian.
As suggested, for the converse to be true, if you have such an involution, it has to be $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ thus $G$ must be abelian, but it needs to have only one fixed point, and this is the case iff you have no element of order $2$. Since $2$ is prime, Lagrange's theorem gives you that $G$ must be of odd order.

Notice that you only need $h$ to be surjective, but as @Geoffrey Trang mentioned, the only way to prove surjectivity is to prove injectivity since the cardinality is finite: indeed in infinite groups $h$ is not necessarily surjective.


For a finite group $G$, there exists an involution in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ having only one fixed point if and only $G$ is abelian and of odd order.

@GeoffreyTrang Thanks for the correction, indeed !
